# How do I prevent files from being sent to the staging area?

Tags: git, commit, staging

I am working on a project that relates several files, some of which I want to add toa `git` repository and some of which I do not. By running `git add .` I would add all my files with untracked changes into the staging area, what if I want to run that command in such a way that all the files with untracked changes EXCEPT those I do not want to sent to the staging area are to be sent to the staging area from now on, such that I do not have to type all the files one by one.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
> should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should I track the .gitignore folder to commit?

Comment: You should commit the .gitignore file.